# Custom "undo" for Webview

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, webview, first-responder

**OK, here's the situation. I have:**

- A `Webview`
- Lots of `NSTextField`s
- Other unrelated controls

Normally, the **Edit** > **Undo** menu item links to First Responder's `undo:` action. And everything works fine + you can even "undo" while typing in an `NSTextField`.

Now, what if I want to handle this "undo" action, in a different way, only for my WebView.

**I've been thinking of two approaches:**

- Link the "Undo" item to a custom action and check who is the First Responder. If it's the Webview, then do what needs to be done. Else, "pass" the event to the control. (However, when attempting a `[FIRST_RESPONDER performSelector:@selector(undo:)]`, first it doesn't seem to recognize the selector and last but not least nothing happens.)
- Link the "Undo" to the first responder's `undo:`(as usual), subclass the Webview and add a custom `- (void)undo:(id)sender` action. In that case though, when the webview is active, the "Undo" item is grayed-out, so I can't do anything whatsoever, not even check whether the custom method would be called.

---

Suggestions? How would you go about that?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the answer: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebEditingDelegate_Protocol/

Also reference this: [Removing undo actions for a WebView's NSUndoManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8319146/removing-undo-actions-for-a-webviews-nsundomanager)